# How to map the minimum value of a list to 0 of CDF using EmpiricalDistribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

Is there an option to map the minimum value of a list to 0 using `CDF` of `EmpiricalDistribution`?

**EDIT**

I'm looking for the inverse of the `Quantile` function, which by definition equals 0 at the min value, and 1 at the max value. In fac, using `CDF` of `EmpiricalDistribution` is motivated by Sjoerd's answer to [my question on that topic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4395/how-can-an-inversequantile-or-an-interval-valued-quantile-function-be-implemente)

**END EDIT**

Given a list of random reals in `[1,2]`:

```
lst = Table[RandomReal[{1, 2}], 10]
```

> {1.77852, 1.06913, 1.59777, 1.95967, 1.64152, 1.77021, 1.16423,
>   1.66417, 1.59076, 1.08503}

Note that the `Max` value of the list maps to 1, but the `Min` maps to a very small but positive value, so I suspect there's some logic that involves less than versus less than or equal thats to blame.

```
lst // AssociationMap[CDF[EmpiricalDistribution[lst], #] &]
```

> <|1.77852 -> 0.9, 1.06913 -> 0.1, 1.59777 -> 0.5, 
>    1.95967 -> 1, 1.64152 -> 0.6, 1.77021 -> 0.8, 1.16423 -> 0.3, 
>    1.66417 -> 0.7, 1.59076 -> 0.4, 1.08503 -> 0.2|>

Same goes for random integers:

```
lst = Table[RandomInteger[{1, 100}], 10]
```

> {3, 22, 40, 90, 97, 98, 72, 37, 53, 30}

Gives again a CDF whose max value is 1 but with positive min value:

```
lst // AssociationMap[CDF[EmpiricalDistribution[lst], #] &]
```

> <|3->1/10,22->1/5,40->1/2,90->4/5,97->9/10,98->1,72->7/10,37->2/5,53->3/5,30->3/10|>

Comment: The usual definition of a CDF is $Pr(X\leq x)$ but is what you want $Pr(X \lt x)$?

Answer (score 2):

If you want $Pr(X < x)$ rather than $Pr(X \leq x)$ (the usual definition of a CDF), then the following function might work for you:

```
lst = Table[RandomReal[{1, 2}], 10];
dist = EmpiricalDistribution[lst];
cdfModified[x_] := Probability[X < x, X \[Distributed] dist];

cdfModified[Min[lst]]
(* 0 *)
```

But that means you'll get

```
cdfModified[Max[lst]]
(* 0.9 *)
```

Stating what you need in mathematical/statistical terms such as $Pr(X<x)$ would clarify things.  Any proposed manipulation of the data in isolation of a model or definition of the objective can likely lead to undesirable consequences.

For example, just dropping the smallest value will achieve one part of the stated objective: the value of the empirical CDF will be zero at that minimum value.  However, the value will now also be zero for any value less than the 2nd smallest value.

**Edit:**

From your comment what you want to do doesn't seem unclear but rather imaginative in terms of properties of probability and statistics.  (Or, it might very well be that I'm not so imaginative.)

One could simply replace the smallest value with the smallest value incremented by a very small amount.  (Again, I cannot imagine a situation where that would make sense.  So I offer this just to see if I'm understanding what you want to do.)

```
(* Generate some data and sort it from low to high *)
lst = Table[RandomReal[{1, 2}], 10]
lst = Sort[lst]

(* Save the minimum value *)
minlst = lst[[1]]

(* Add a small amount to the minimum value based on the smallest differences
among all of the values *)
lst[[1]] = lst[[1]] + Min[Differences[lst]]/100

(* Construct the empirical distribution *)
dist = EmpiricalDistribution[lst];

(* Check the value of the empirical CDF with the modified value and the minimum value *)
CDF[dist, minlst]
(* 0 *)
CDF[dist, lst[[1]]]
(* 0.1 *)
```

**Another alternative:**

```
lst = Table[RandomReal[{1, 2}], 10];
minlst = Min[lst];
dist = EmpiricalDistribution[lst];
cdfModified[z_, zmin_] := Piecewise[{{CDF[dist, z], z > zmin}}, 0]

cdfModified[minlst, minlst]
(* 0 *)
cdfModified[minlst + 0.001, minlst]
(* 0.1 *)
```

Comment: Thanks, doesn't help as it creates the mirror problem. If it's not obvious from my q, I'm looking to normalize discrete data list to `[0,1]`

Comment: Why am I being so obstinate about stating that you shouldn't be modifying the common definition of an empirical distribution function?  First, all definitions are arbitrary.  But if one deviates from the common definition/interpretation of a statistical procedure, then one can be mislead.  I'm all for modifying definitions but only when there's at least a proposed justification.  What I see here is what appears to be arbitrary manipulation of the numbers.  Now this forum isn't necessarily the right place for the justification.  But it would get you better answers if you could expound on that.

Comment: I'm looking for the inverse of the `Quantile` function, which by definition equals 0 at the min value, and 1 at the max value. In fact I got the `CDF` of `EmpiricalDistribution` from Sjoerd's answer to my [question on that topic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4395/how-can-an-inversequantile-or-an-interval-valued-quantile-function-be-implemente)

Comment: It would be great if you could add that to your question.

Comment: I edited my question, thanks.

Comment: Sorry to keep being a pain but the `Quantile` function is not invertible for discrete 
 distributions.That' s why I keep asking for a mathematically specific 
question.  If you look at `qTable = Table[{q, Quantile[lst, q]}, {q, 0, 1, 1/10000}];
ListPlot[qTable, Joined -> True]`, you'll see why it can't be inverted.  There is not a 1-to-1 relationship.

Comment: But maybe `InverseFunction` will do what you want.

Comment: Yes I'm aware it's not invertible in the given comain-codomain, but that's not a problem for discrete sets, but consider it as multi-valued function (see Vaughan Pratt's work on Chu spaces and "anti-functions")

Comment: Your last comment convinces me that you can clearly write your question in mathematical terms.  If you do so, you'll reach a wider audience and get better answers.

Comment: the quantile of a finite distribution is a piecewise constant function, so its pseudo-inverse (to borrow from linear algebra) will be a partition of the support of the domain into intervals, each interval being the inverse image of a constant value. Then the min and max of that support are the extremes of the (closure of) the union of those intervals. How to best represent that in WL?

Comment: I still can't image why you'd need a new type of distribution function definition.  (Yes, I probably do have a limited imagination.)  If you have a large sample, then there would be hardly any difference from the standard definition.  So only if you have a small sample size would there be any difference.  Because your request is really about a conceptual issue (as R or Mathematica or SAS could perform whatever you come up with), why not ask this question at stats.stackexchange.com?

Comment: It's not a new type of distribution function- as discussed above it's the pseudo-inverse of the `Quantile` function for any given (finite) distribution. By pseudo, I'm sure can likely use the analogous definition as for Moore Penrose pseudoinverse from linear algebra, ie, `Q Q* Q == Q` and its conjugates.

Comment: Understood.  I still ask "Why do you need this pseudo-inverse of the `Quantile` function?"  What does it do for you that the usual definition doesn't get you?  I'm not at all saying you don't have a reason to do so.  I just don't see that the "why" has been described.  Maybe @SjoerdC.deVries can answer that.  I could think of the meandian which is the average of the mean and the median.  But I'd be hard pressed to think a practical application of that summary statistic.

Comment: Normalizes the data list to the range `[0,1]` leaving its PDF shape invariant.